# JQuery: How to select a div with a specific inline style added by Masonry (after pageload)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm using Masonry to organise a photo layout and it adds inline styles to position the items. eg.

```
<div class="iconicblock item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 402px;">
```

**I need to apply a style to every left item** (containing left: 0px;)

**UPDATE:**
The issue is that the styles are being added later by Masonry, and are not being recognised. These two answers below should ordinarily work:

```
$(".iconicblock[style*='left: 0px']")
```

and

```
if($(this).css('left') == '0px')
```

But they don't work when the styles have been added by Masonry.
Any ideas how I might be able to target these items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
if($(this).css('style') == 'left: 0px')
```

Try (You have to select specific css not complete style)

```
if($(this).css('left') == '0px')
```

Comment: Yes I would totally expect that to work, but it doesn't. Is it maybe because Masonry is injecting the styles after pageload (or something)?

Comment: I can confirm, this code is perfect on straight HTML - it's just not picking up the styles that Masonry is adding. Any ideas?

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because this code is correct - I just needed to apply it on HOVER instead of on pageload (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue was with Masonry being loaded after everything else (using imagesloaded to delay Masonry from applying until after everything else).

But by applying it on "hover" instead, it could then recognise the inline style:

```
$(".iconicblock").hover(
function(){ 
if($(this).css('left') == '0px') $('.iconpopout',this).addClass('left'); 
}
);
```

*(Here I'm applying the css to a particular child element of the div in question)*